# Is there a way to order the destruction and creation in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create an infrastructure on vCenter in Terraform with three different VM resources, each with a redundant copy of itself as a secondary. When making a change to the infrastructure, I don't want to have downtime. However, Terraform just destroys everything at the beginning of an apply. I also need to provision the VMs with Chef in a certain order. How could I make it so it destroys a VM, recreates it, destroys another, recreates it, and so on? In other words, perform a rolling deployment.

I initially set `count = 2` for each VM to produce primary and secondary VMs, but I could not order creation that way, so I split them out. I tried using `create_before_destroy` but vCenter does not allow having two VMs with the same name. I also tried using `depends_on`. This works for ordering the creation of the VMs, but it still just destroys the entire infrastructure at once.

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm1_prim" {
  ...
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm1_sec" {
  depends_on = [vsphere_virtual_machine.vm1_prim]
  ...
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm2_prim" {
  depends_on = [vsphere_virtual_machine.vm1.sec]
  ...
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm2_sec" {
  depends_on = [vsphere_virtual_machine.vm2_prim]
  ...
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm3_prim" {
  ...
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm3_sec" {
  depends_on = [vsphere_virtual_machine.vm3_prim]
  ...
}
```

I suppose performing the following would likely work, but it doesn't seem like the "Terraform" thing to do:

```sh
terraform apply --auto-approve -target=vsphere_virtual_machine.vm1_prim -target=vsphere_virtual_machine.vm3_prim
terraform apply --auto-approve -target=vsphere_virtual_machine.vm1_sec -target=vsphere_virtual_machine.vm2_prim -target=vsphere_virtual_machine.vm3_sec
terraform apply --auto-approve -target=vsphere_virtual_machine.vm2_sec
```

I expect Terraform to work in this order:

- destroy vm1_prim and vm3_prim
- create vm1_prim and vm3_prim
- destroy vm1_sec and vm3_sec
- create vm1_sec and vm3_sec
- destroy vm2_prim
- create vm2_prim
- destroy vm2_sec
- create vm2_sec

Instead it does the following:

- destroy vm2_sec and vm3_sec
- destroy vm2_prim and vm3_prim
- destroy vm1_sec
- destroy vm1_prim
- create vm1_prim and vm3_prim
- create vm1_sec and vm3_sec
- create vm2_prim
- create vm2_sec

Comment: I have a potential idea I can add as an answer. But first, I'd like to understand a little bit more about the issue. You mention you "don't want to have downtime". But even ordering the destruction of VMs one after another would happen fairly quickly. Do you just want to make sure that a VM is created _immediately_ before destroying the initial one or does it need to wait some time (ie health checking or a handoff period so traffic moves to the second)?

Comment: That is a good point. It would probably be a good idea to perform simple health checks to make sure the Chef provisioning worked. I don't think there is a way in vSphere to create a new VM before destroying the old one because of name conflicts. That would be ideal if it could though.

Comment: I do this with some resources by using https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/random/r/id.html to generate names. You can then either use `keepers` or `taint` the `random_id` resource before applying to force creation of a new `vsphere_virtual_machine`. But this still doesn't solve the problem of a VM going away before the new one is ready.

Comment: I also have to have static IP and MAC addresses. That would probably cause an issue with creation before destruction as well. Since this is high availability, I feel like my plan to destroy and recreate the primary VMs and then the secondary VMs should work. The load balancers should be able to handle that.